# What is a good open source alternative to orielly's MultipartRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, multipart

What is a good alternative open source library to orielly's MultipartRequest for handling uploaded files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) has become the defacto standard for this now. It's pretty useful, has lots of options for handling larger uploads, and is used by Spring MVC as the backing implementation for this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) has worked for me in the past.  I believe it's what the Spring framework uses internally to handle multipart requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you've made the leap to Servlet 3.0, you can annotate your servlet to support file upload.

From the [spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315):

> ## File upload
>
> If a request is of type
>   multipart/form-data and if the servlet
>   handling the request is annotated
>   using the @MultipartConfig as defined
>   in Section 8.1.5, “@MultipartConfig”
>   on page 8-64, the HttpServletRequest
>   can make available the various parts
>   of the multipart request via the
>   following methods
>
> - public Collection getParts()
> - public Part getPart(String name).

Comment: See for examples: [Uploading files in Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html). By the way, Glassfish v3 Java EE 6 uses Commons FileUpload behind the scenes for the task. It's indeed the *defacto standard* as @skaffman said.

Answer (score 0):

Is javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart usable in this context?